# Custom Culture not applying when running an Azure DevOps build pipeline

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a function that converts a string that represents a number into a custom currency format. I need to invert the separators (turn commas into dots and dots into commas) and add the $ symbol in front.

**Example input format:** "70000.50"

**Example output required format:** "$ 70.000,50"

My function is this

```
    public static string ToCurrencyFormat(this string str)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
        {
            str = $"$ {Convert.ToDecimal(str, new CultureInfo("en-US")):N2}";
        }

        return str;
    }
```

This function works fine on my computer.

The problem is that when i run tests of this function in a build pipeline in Azure DevOps, the tests fail with this error:

```
Error Message:
Expected member Body[2] to be
"Value: $ 70.000,00", but
"Value: $ 70,000.00" differs near ",00" (index 12).
```

It seems that a different culture than the one I'm specifying is being used to convert the decimal.

Someone told me that i should change the culture in the server, or in the dockerfile of my application.

My questions are:

Why is the function failing to use "en-US" as culture when running in Azure DevOps?

Why are server/dockerfile culture taking precedence over the one i'm specifying as parameter?

Comment: Can you show where you are specifying culture for ToString call?

Comment: I'm specifying the culture on the 'ToDecimal' call, after that i'm converting it to string again using the :N2. An equivalent line would be:

str = $"$ {Convert.ToDecimal(str, new CultureInfo("en-US")).ToString("N2")}";

Comment: The function isn't failing. The culture applies only to parsing the input to a decimal, not to formatting that decimal into a new string. Formatting is done using the thread's default locale, which on Azure DevOps is probably `en-US`. Instead of creating a new CultureInfo object on every call it's better to use `CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")`

Comment: @EmilianoRodriguez please [edit] post to clarify that - from the title and the body of the post it feels like you specifying culture somewhere for formatting, but in your comment you explicitly stated that you don't (and presumably you are not interested in something like `123m.ToString(new CultureInfo("es-es"))` ). Also while editing consider removing unrelated decimal parsing code - for [MRE] it would be more beneficial to specify constant inline (`70000m` in your case).

Comment: (rude and unfriendly comment here, feel free to flag) Note that it is very bad idea to imply that currency of the value matches current output culture (which in turn may or may not match region of the user).

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so there's a little to get through here.  First, it isn't clear why your input is a string and not a number.  If it must be a string, let's separate the step of converting that into a number out.  In your example code this is the only stage you're setting the culture specifically.

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Note this is really just a wrapper around TryParse (so needless) but perhaps you do other
/// processing at this stage (undocumented)
/// </summary>
/// <param name="stringForm"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static bool ParseNumber(string stringForm,out decimal result)
{
   //Allow leading currency, decimal point, thousands separator - in your example the input number 
   // ONLY contains a decimal separator, in which case you don't need the other two styles.
   var style = NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol 
     | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint 
     | NumberStyles.AllowThousands;

   //You don't specify whether the incoming string has a culture.. it might, although - again - 
   // in the example you gave it looks like it's really a number and not a string at all.  
   // If you know the culture, use `new CultureInfo()` here
   if (!decimal.TryParse(stringForm, style, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out result)) return false;

   //Do other things with the number
   
   return true;
}
```

Now to format a number as you've requested..  using the [`C` format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#currency-format-specifier-c) gets us a currency indicator too.

```cs
public static string FormatForCurrency(decimal number)
{
   var format = new NumberFormatInfo
   {
      CurrencySymbol = "$",
      CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ",",
      CurrencyDecimalDigits = 2,
      CurrencyGroupSeparator = "."
   };
   return number.ToString("C", format);//$70.000,50
}
```

If you must have string based numbers, then to use these together you'd use code like the following:

```cs
public static string UseStringNumberAndFormatAsCurrency(string numberAsString)
{
   if (!ParseNumber(numberAsString, out var num))
   {
      //You may want to throw an exception instead, you could also consider `decimal.Parse`
      // instead of `decimal.TryParse` for this
      Console.WriteLine("Invalid string number: ", numberAsString);
      return null;
   }
   return FormatForCurrency(num);
}
```